# Android studio icon problem- ic_launcher files deleted

Tags: xml, android-studio, icons

What happens when I accidentally delete the ic_launcher and ic_launcher_round files in android studio
Res>mipmap>ic_launcher
Now i have errors in my code.
Is it possible to redeem this error or do I have to start my project all over again

I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

first create new project than copy that "minimap" folder after that from where you have deleted past in resource folder that you have copied from the new project. Your problem will solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the new app icon, choose `file -> new -> image asset`. then import your icon.